# ASP.NET MVC View List<MyViewModel> error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET MVC Core application, I'm getting the following error when controller passes the view:

**Error**:

```
'List<GrantsViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'StateName' and no extension method 'StateName' accepting a first argument of type 'List<GrantsViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**Models**:

```
public class StateName
    {
        [Key]
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string StateNumber { get; set; }
     }

public class AnnualGrant
    {
        [Key]
        public int GrantNo_Id { get; set; }
        public string StateNumber { get; set; }
        public int FiscalYear { get; set; }
        public string GrantNo { get; set; }
    }

public class MyProjectContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyProjectContext (DbContextOptions<MyProjectContext> options) : base(options)
        { }
        public DbSet<StateName> StateNames { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AnnualGrant> AnnualGrants { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public class GrantsViewModel
    {
        public int GrantNo_Id { get; set; }
        public string StateNumber { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string GrantNo { get; set; }
        public int FiscalYear { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
public class DbTestController : Controller
    {
        private MyProjContext _context;

        public DbTestController(MyProjContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

    public IActionResult GrantNumbers()
    {
        var qryVM = from s in _context.StateNames
               join g in _context.AnnualGrants on s.StateNumber equals g.StateNumber into sg
               from r in sg.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new GrantsViewModel() { StateNumber = s.StateNumber,StateName= s.State, GrantNo= (r == null ? String.Empty : r.GrantNo), FiscalYear = (r == null ? 1900 : r.FiscalYear) };

       return View(qryVM.ToList());
    }
}
```

**View**: NOTE: **The error occurs in this view**:

```
@model List<MyProjet.Models.GrantsViewModel>

<form asp-controller="DbTest" asp-action="GrantNumbers" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StateName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GrantNo)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="StateName" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GrantNo)
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The model is a `List<>`, which has no `StateName` property.  You want that property from an *element* in the list.  Something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().StateName)
```

It may seem a little strange, because it feels like it's actually pulling an element from the list (which could throw an error in this case if the list is empty).  But the framework doesn't actually drill into the list itself.  The framework is really looking to reflect on the type, not iterate the instance.  And this is simply telling it where in the type system to look.

Comment: And @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().GrantNo) :)

Comment: Don't you worry that it may throw an exception if model list is empty?

Comment: @serhiyb: Intuitively that feels like it would be the case, but the framework doesn't actually execute the query.  This is just for reflecting into the type, not for iterating the collection.

Comment: TIL, thanks @David.

Comment: @David Thank you for trying to help. `model.First().StateName` works but I'm still getting the error in `<input asp-for="StateName" />` line. Intellisense is not recognizing the `StateName` displaying the same error message as in my post above.

Comment: @nam: Admittedly I haven't used `asp-for`, but the examples seem to show similar intellisense at play.  Does the same syntax work?

Comment: @David I'm using [ASP.NET Tag Helpers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html). `model.First().StateName ` did not work in `<input asp-for="StateName" />` but following worked: `<input asp-for="@Model.First().StateName" />`. Also, thank you for explaining the cause of the error in your original post.

Comment: @David Although <input asp-for="@Model.First().StateName" /> does not give an error but in the foreach loop it returns only the first element. In each table cell for State Name it is supposed to return a nique State Name, e.g., Virginia, Ohio, Iowa, ..., etc.

Answer (score 1):

David's answer should solve your problem. Here is another solution.

There is another overload of this method which works with `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
```

It works if your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<T>`.

So change your `@model List<MyProjet.Models.GrantsViewModel>` to

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProjet.Models.GrantsViewModel>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(g=>g.StateName)
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td><input asp-for="StateName" /></td>              
         </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Remember it works only if your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<T>`, It won't work if it is `List<T>` or `IList<T>`

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. Where in my project do I need to add the overload of your method?

Comment: You do not need to add anything. You simply use it(`@Html.DisplayNameFor(g=>g.StateName))`. Read the answer please.

Comment: After changing the code to what you suggested, I'm still getting the same error in `<input input asp-for="StateName" /` with slightly different wording: `IEnumerable<GrantsViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'StateName' `. Moreover, Intellisense does not recognize StateName in `@Html.DisplayNameFor(g=>g.StateName)` But it does not display an error if I hard code `g.StateName`
`